# Wiring up Symfony2 services in the DIC using configuration parameters

Tags: symfony

I'd like to be able to wire up services from configuration parameters so that I can use a mock implementation of a web service client in the dev environment and I can use the proper client in prod env.

Here is a snippet from my services.xml:

```
<parameters>
    ...
    <parameter key="api_client.api_service.id">ic_domain_security.api_mock_service</parameter>
    ...
</parameters>

<services>
...
    <service id="ic_domain_security.api_client"
                 class="%api_client.class%"
                 public="true">
            <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="domainApiClient"/>
            <argument type="service" id="%api_client.api_service.id%"/>
            <call method="setLogger">
                <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null"/>
            </call>
        </service>

        <service id="ic_domain_security.api_restful_webservice"
                 class="IC\DomainSecurityBundle\ApiClient\ApiRestfulWebService"
                 public="false">
            <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="domainApiRestfulWebService"/>
            <argument>%ic_domain_security.service_url%</argument>
            <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null"/>
        </service>

        <service id="ic_domain_security.api_mock_service"
                 class="IC\DomainSecurityBundle\Tests\Mock\ApiMockService"
                 public="false">
            <call method="setLogger">
                <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null"/>
            </call>
        </service>
...
</services>
```

The line `<argument type="service" id="%api_client.api_service.id%"/>` is trying to define the service to pass based on a parameter. So I'm eventually trying to push out the `api_client.api_service.id` parameter to configuration file(s).

Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be possible to define service ids using parameters and I'm getting the following error:

```
ServiceNotFoundException: The service "ic_domain_security.api_client" has a dependency on a non-existent service "%api_client.api_service.id%".
```

Is there a way do what I explained above so that service ids can be passed using configuration parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to do what you are trying to do is to define a semantic configuration for your bundle. Anyway I don't think that you can do this without writing some PHP code.

This means that you should write a Configuration class and a Dependency Injection Extension class. It is quite an easy process, though it is not exhaustively documented on Symfony2 docs. My advice is to take some simple bundle (e.g. I learned very much reading FOSUserBundle) and see how they define their configuration.

[Here you can find an introduction](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) to the DIC extension system.

Answer (score 2):

To allow the class of a service to be defined in configuration, you would use semantic configuration (as mentioned above).  An example follows:

Here is a simple service (a service can be any php class):

```
<?php

namespace Sample\Bundle\ServiceBundle\Service;

class Awesomeness {
  public function doSomething()
  {
    return 'I did something';
  }
}
```

There are several ways to wire the service into the Symfony2 service container.  For this example we will create a services.xml file at ServiceBundle/Resources/config (this is described all over the Symfony2 docs):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>

    <container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
        <services>
                <service id="sample_service_bundle.awesomess" class="%sample_service_bundle.awesomeness.class%">
                </service>
        </services>
</container>
```

Notice that I didn't add the standard  section to the services.xml.  This is intentional.  We will be modifying the bundle's extension class and semantic configuration class to inject the parameter from config.yml.

To allow the service class to be defined in configuration, we first will add the configuration to DependencyInjection/Configuration.php:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('brain_glove_site');

        $rootNode
                ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('awesomeness_class')->cannnotBeEmpty()->defaultValue('Sample\\Bundle\\ServiceBundle\\Service\\Awesomeness')->end()
                ->end()
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Here we have created a new configuration parameter called 'awesomeness_class' that could be set in config.yml and provided it with a default value.

However, we still need create the actual parameter that the service can use.  This is done in the extension class your bundle will use.  If your bundle is called SampleServiceBundle, then the class you edit would be DependencyInjection\SampleServiceExtension:

```
class SampleServiceExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));

        $loader->load('services.xml');

        $container->setParameter('sample_service_bundle.awesomeness.class', $config['awesomeness_class']);
    }
}
```

The $container->setParameter() method call injects a parameter into your container that will then be used by your service definition.

At this point, there is nothing else you need to do to use your service as usual.

If you want to change the class that the service instantiates in configuration, you could edit config_dev.yml:

```
...
sample_service:
    awesomeness_class: SomeOtherBundle/SomeOtherClass
```

And now your application would be using a different class for this service.

Answer (score 0):

I have never figured out how to define dynamic arguments (with a parameter as service id). The only way I found to get that working is using a factory AND semantic configuration.

Basically what you should do is:

- Define a parameter using semantic configuration
- Create a factory that can return the correct service based on that parameter (your factory will need ServiceContainer instance itself for that)
- Define a service that use the factory to be instantiated (this will give you a service id which reference a dynamically created object)
- Use this service name a dependence of other services.

You can found out information about DIC and factories here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html

Its a bit tricky because you need the factory class, but it works. I'm not sure it is the only way to do that, but still not found a better one.

Here you can find a little example of what I have done: https://gist.github.com/32378f4000df482a8b9b

It is not the entire codebase, but you can see "vich_uploader.storage" service which use a factory service to instantiate the actual service. StorageFactory will return the correct service based on 'vich_uploader.storage_service' DIC parameter, which is defined by bundle semantic configuration.

All other services will use "vich_uploader.storage" as argument.